What's the difference between ProcessCmdKey, Hook, and KeyUp?
I am using hotkeys when for my VB.NET 8 / WinForms app.
I find resources on the forums about working with hotkeys differently.
There is ProcessCmdKey method, HookCallBack method, and KeyUp method.
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
If keyData = Keys.F1 Then
    Debug.WriteLine("F1 was hit")
    Return True
ElseIf keyData = Keys.F2 Then
    Debug.WriteLine("F2 was hit")
    Return True
End If
Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function

    Private Delegate Function LowLevelKeyboardProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr

Private Function HookCallback(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    If nCode >= 0 AndAlso wParam = CType(&H100, IntPtr) Then ' WM_KEYDOWN
        Dim vkCode As Keys = CType(Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam), Keys)
        If vkCode = Keys.F1 Then
            Debug.WriteLine("F1 was hit")
            Return CType(1, IntPtr)
        ElseIf vkCode = Keys.F2 Then
            Debug.WriteLine("F2 was hit")
            Return CType(1, IntPtr)
        End If
    End If
    Return CallNextHookEx(hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam)

End Function


Private Sub MacInjection_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
If e.KeyCode = Keys.F1 Then
    Debug.WriteLine("F1 was hit")
ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F2 Then
    Debug.WriteLine("F2 was hit")
End If
End Sub

As you can see there are multiple ways of doing this but I am never getting the message "F1/F2 was hit".
KeyPreview is set as true and I am running the app in administrator mode but for some reason when I place a breakpoint at it, it hit it for all other keys on the keyboard including f3-f12 but not for f1 and f2.

If you want to use hotkeys, is there a particular reason that you're not using the RegisterHotKey API?

I would assume that F1 at least would have special meaning and wouldn't make it to your control.

Hi, I tried with the RegisterHotKey API but nothing seems to work. So is there a way to have my app overpower the F1 meaning for that key while it's running at least?

Your problem is you are mixing multiple ways of doing the same thing and they are confusing each other.
Try the following:

Start a completely new Windows Forms project

Use the IDE to set Form1.KeyPreview to True

Handle the Form1.KeyUp event
Public Class Form1   
  Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F1 Then
      MsgBox("F1 pressed")
    End If
  End Sub
End Class



The form needs to have focus. The above code works for me using .NET 8.0
